# run bundle install in Ruby on Rails new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails with Lynda.com. In one of the early videos, the instructor creates a new project using the command

```
rails new simple_cms -d mysql
```

After he ran that, he got some output like this, which I also got, but at the bottom of mine, I saw "run bundle install". His doesn't have that...

**Is that a command I'm supposed to run?**

```
   create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You **first** need to install the bundler gem:

```
gem install bundler
```

Once it's done, run:

```
bundle
```

or:

```
bundle install
```

(same thing)

Comment: I had to update my certs before I could use gem install to get bundler.  I found the following article/comment useful:
https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#gistcomment-1925425

Answer (score 7):

[Bundler](http://bundler.io/) is a gem dependency manager. It ensures that all the gems you use (chunks of third party code) have their dependencies (other gems that they rely on) satisfied.

You should run `bundle install`, as this installs all the gems Rails will need to get going.

The video you're watching probably concerns an old version of Rails. The current version (by that I mean version 3 and above) uses Bundler by default. Versions lower than 3 did not ship with Bundler support.

The fantastic [Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler) has a bit more on Bundler, and [loads of stuff](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=27) on Rails 3.

Comment: I ran "bundle install" and it said, "could not locate gemfile" . The video is using rails 3.0. I am using rails 3.1

Comment: Rails should generate a Gemfile by default. You need to `cd` into the root of the Rails application (so probably `cd simple_cms`) and then run the `bundle install` command.

Comment: Just a word of warning that rails 3.0 and 3.1 have significantly different components and since you mentioned you are beginning rails, you might want to consider start using rails 3.0 so your code will have more odds of working as you follow along.

Comment: @Jim Munro -thanks for the tip. so when I load install rails, do I just specify 3.0, will that also make sure 3.0 version of active record and other necessary files are installed?

Comment: Yes. If you run `gem install rails --version=3.0.0` then Bundler will take take of the dependencies, installing the appropriate versions ActiveRecord and other related gems.

Comment: *Cough* Have you tried `gem install bundler` first, Michael? *cough*

Comment: It certainly sounds like he has because after running `bundle install` he gets `Could not locate Gemfile`, which is an error Bundler throws.

Comment: Please update the link of 'Bundler' website, it is redirecting to some wrong domain. Change it to bundler.io

Answer (score 2):

This issue caught me off guard. However, I was ultimately at fault. I had created a shell alias of `rails="bundle exec rails"`
And I had forgotten about this, as it served to make working with my other projects easier. However, the "rails new" command is incompatible with such an alias. D'oh.

Comment: I may not have had bundler installed correctly. I'm not exactly sure on what the issue might have been.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you have to run `gem install bundler` first. This will install your bundler, that you need to install gems with `bundle install`. More info about [this topic here](https://kolosek.com/rails-bundle-install-and-gemfile).